# Rails Render JSON Object instead of entire array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In my controller I have the present code that results in a JSON array, even though there is only one result:

```
def getSharedSpecial
    @result = Campaign.find_by_sql("SELECT 
                                     id
                                    ,name
                                    ,image
                                    ,ad_caption
                                    ,ad_details
                                    FROM campaigns 
                                    WHERE id = " + params[:shared_campagin_id].to_s + " 
                                    LIMIT 1;")

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: { special_shared: @result }}
    end         
end
```

returns:

```
"special_shared":[
     {
"id":41,
"name":"tester the way",
"image":{
      "url":"/uploads/campaign/image/41/Gilded_pic.jpg"
        },
"ad_caption":"yfftitu6",
"ad_details":"jku"
      }
   ]
}
```

As can be seen given the `[]`, this is a JSON array.
How can I create just an object and not an entire array?

Comment: Could `@result` ever contain more than one result?  If so, you should leave it as is.  If no, then show us the code that creates the `@results` as it is what should be fixed.

Comment: ok, the code is SQL, added

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `find_by_sql` always returns an array even though you are only looking for a single record. There is no need to use `find_by_sql` and you've opened yourself to SQL injection attacks by doing so, so just write the finder the traditional way:

```
@result = Campaign.select(:id, :name, :image, :ad_caption, :ad_details).find(params[:shared_campagin_id])
```